# Copy data from one spreadsheet to another onchange

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Pardon me as I am fairly new to this and may be missing something easy.

I have a spreadsheet that I create data from a template, run a script over it to create forms which become user tasks.  The edit URL from the form is used to complete the task and it records on the master sheet (Sheet2) with the status, attachments, data stamp, and email address.  From there I am trying to create a list of tasks that need approvals from my master sheet to another sheet (LOG) on a different spreadsheet but I am having issues with `openByID` for my target spreadsheet.  It says it is undefined.  I can get this to work in sheets in the same spreadsheet but I would like it in a different spreadsheet if possible.  This is all done onChange of Sheet2 when status changes to yes and only for specific tasks (Verification Report, Maintenance Memo, Check Report)

```
function onChange() {
  // moves a row from one sheet to another sheet when a value is entered in a column and another column has specific values
  var columnNumberToWatch = /* column D */ 4; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var valueToWatch = "yes";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "LOG";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var activeRow = cell.getRow();
  var taskCheck=sheet.getRange(activeRow, 2);

  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openByID("my spreadsheet id");
  var targetSheet = target.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);


  if (sheet.getName() != sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo &&
      cell.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch &&
      cell.getValue().toLowerCase() == valueToWatch && 
      (taskCheck.getValue() == "Verfication Report" || taskCheck.getValue() == "Maintenance Memo" || taskCheck.getValue() == "Check Report"))
  {
    sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange);
  }
}
```

Comment: When posting questions asking for errors, make sure you include the exact text of the error (not a screencap or summary of it - the exact *text*), and additionally include what you have tried to do to understand and/or resolve said error (and what happened as a result of each attempt)

Comment: Not sure I understand why you are using `onChange` for a trigger.  `onChange` is reserved for changes to the **structure** of a spreadsheet, i.e.: adding/removing a sheet, adding/deleting rows/columns.  What you are doing is editing a cell in the sheet.  That should be `onEdit`.  Otherwise, what do the logs or execution transcript show?